# cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_{2n}(x)$

Tags: cyclotomic-polynomials

Question is:

> "Show that $\Phi_{2n}(x)=\Phi_n(-x)$ for all odd numbers $n>1$"

I try to prove this as follow,

$\prod_{d \mid 2n} \Phi_d(x) =x^{2n}-1 = (x^n-1)(x^n+1) = -(x^n-1)((-x)^n-1) = -\prod_{d \mid n} \Phi_d(x)\Phi_d(-x)$

Then I write,

$ \Phi_n(x)\Phi_{2n}(x)\prod_{d \mid n; d\neq n}\Phi_d(x)\Phi_{2d}(x)  = - \Phi_n(x)\Phi_{n}(-x)\prod_{d \mid n;d\neq n} \Phi_d(x)\Phi_d(-x)$

Then

$ \Phi_{2n}(x)\prod_{d \mid n; d\neq n}\Phi_{2d}(x)  = - \Phi_{n}(-x)\prod_{d \mid n; d\neq n} \Phi_d(-x)$

My claim is $ \prod_{d \mid n; d\neq n}\Phi_{2d}(x)  = - \prod_{d \mid n; d\neq n} \Phi_d(-x)$

But I did not prove this claim.. Any idea?

or dou you have another proof?

Comment: Sure: if $\zeta$ is a primitive $m$-th root of unity, where $m$ is odd, then $-\zeta$ is ia primitive $2m$-th root of unity.

Comment: This question appeared at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546993/).

Comment: @MarkoRiedel but this is different solution from mine.. Can I improve my proof? I can not move on any more